# Examples of theories that assume the existence of an "External Reality"?

Tags: cosmology, multiverse, laws-of-physics

In this paper written by physicist Max Tegmark (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0646.pdf) it talks about "External Reality Hypothesis". Specifically, he says:

> Although many physicists subscribe to the ERH and dedicate
>   their careers to the search for a deeper understanding of this assumed external reality, the ERH is not universally
>   accepted

and

> We will see that, although
>   it sounds innocuous, the ERH has sweeping implications
>   for physics if taken seriously.
>   Physics theories aim to describe how this assumed external
>   reality works.

So it seems that there are theories in physics which accept the existence of this so-called "External Reality".

Apparently in the paper no example of these types of physical theories appear. So, do you know of any theory which assumes this? What theories is Tegmark talking about?

Comment: How can you have a theory that does _not_ subscribe to extern reality, except for solipsism.

Answer (score 1):

For non relativistic quantum mechanics the [Bohmian  mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohmian_mechanics) theory is one such example and there are a number of people working on it trying to expand it to the relativistic case.

> The de Broglie–Bohm theory, also known as the pilot wave theory, Bohmian mechanics, Bohm's interpretation, and the causal interpretation, is an interpretation of quantum mechanics. In addition to a wavefunction on the space of all possible configurations, it also postulates an actual configuration that exists even when unobserved

For the non relativistic case it is an equivalent mathematically interpretation of the data reproducing the Copenhagen results ( what is taught in first year quantum mechanics courses),

[Gerald t'Hooft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_%27t_Hooft) is also working on finding a theory with a classical mechanics framework that will reproduce the quantum mechanical results.

> 't Hooft has "deviating views on the physical interpretation of quantum theory".He believes that there could be a deterministic explanation underlying quantum mechanics. Using a speculative model he has argued that such a theory could avoid the usual Bell inequality arguments that would disallow such a local hidden variable theory. In 2016 he published a book length exposition of his ideas which, according to 't Hooft, has encountered mixed reactions.

These are the two that I know of, but there must be more on these lines, not so well known.

From the paper in your quote, these are of the type of ERH.

> I explore physics implications of the External Reality Hypothesis(ERH) that there exists an external physical reality completely independent of us humans

All of classical physics theories are ERH theories and people working on deterministic models will fall in that category.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I would also like to ask you if some indeterministic theory could also be an ERH theory @annav

Comment: you mean alternative to quantum mechanics? I am not aware of any such theories. On the other hand one could say that string theories  postulate the underlying reality is strings, and these theoriew are  quantum mechanical.

Comment: also, Tegmark's hypothesis of Mathematical Universe Hypothesis assumes the existence of an External Reality where all universes described by any kind of mathematical structure would exist, but in the example you put, particularly 't Hooft's theory, this model would only be able to produce computable structures (en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics) . What about non computable structures? @annav

Answer (score -1):

Descartes sought as a science an explanation of nature with things and things. You can control natural phenomena by controlling things. This is the basis of reductionism. It is clear that mathematics is not a things. We can not control gravity because we do not explain it in things.